# React - search component to filter array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently, I have been searching through to understand the development behind a live search input, the content being an array. In my case, the array is being used to create a file tree. **All the code is here:** **https://codesandbox.io/s/815p3k3vkj**

After some investigation and looking through some working examples, the solution seemed simple, but then I understood that I was still confused about it's creation. **So, I defined the initial state, but I'm confused of what to do next, to connect the search with the array.**

**So, I started to do something like this:**

```
export class SearchEngine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
  }

  inputChange(e) {
    const content = e.target.value;
    this.props.onChange();
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    onChange: (search) => {

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input placeholder="Search the tree..." onChange={this.inputChange}/>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchEngine;
```

And here is the **array** and `<FileTree>`:

```
let data = [
  {
    type: "directory",
    name: ".",
    contents: [
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./bin",
        contents: [{ type: "file", name: "./bin/greet" }]
      },
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./lib",
        contents: [{ type: "file", name: "./lib/greeting.rb" }]
      },
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./spec",
        contents: [
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/01_greeting_spec.rb" },
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/02_cli_spec.rb" },
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/spec_helper.rb" }
        ]
      },
      { type: "file", name: "./CONTRIBUTING.md" },
      { type: "file", name: "./Gemfile" },
      { type: "file", name: "./Gemfile.lock" },
      { type: "file", name: "./LICENSE.md" },
      { type: "file", name: "./README.md" }
    ]
  }
];

export class FileTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNode: null
    };
    this.setActiveNode = this.setActiveNode.bind(this);
  }

  setActiveNode(name) {
    this.setState({ activeNode: name });
    this.props.liftStateUp(name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="padd_top">
        {renderTree(
          this.props.root || root,
          this.setActiveNode,
          this.state.activeNode
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FileTree;
```

I appreciate all the clarity given in this matter and I want to thank in advance all the help you can provide. I'm a ReactJS newbie and in the middle of new understandings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have no defined `props.onChange` function inside `SearchEngine` class. If your component depends on `prop.onChange` being a function and you are calling it directly you have to setup required prop

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


class SearchEngine extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
}
```

alternatively you can guard your component with

```js
class SearchEngine extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    onChange: () => {}
  }
}
```

which will in fact do nothing in case prop is not passed but it will not crash. From your example is not clear what onChange should do but you are not passing it from `index.js` where you are rendering `SearchEngine`

EDIT: working solution https://y7p6zlmpyx.codesandbox.io/

Comment: @RCohen I've added working example, I didn't pay attention to refactor, just providing working example

Comment: Another thing, I noticed that when you search a file from the array, like `greeting.rb`, this content disappears. What is missing there? @Milos Mosovsky

Comment: I think it's because it needs to match also dir name, try to search for `spec` or `CONTRIBUTING` I didn't do heavy lifting for you and didn't optimize to code to work for all possible options, but just shown you next steps. I think with the example you can tweak the filtering mechanism easily if you have `searchTerm` in all components. You can do only `file` search or `dir` search or both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169993/discussion-between-rcohen-and-milos-mosovsky).

Comment: Why is `static defaultProps = {
    onChange: () => {}
  };` empty?
@Milos Mosovsky

Comment: What about the `null` inside `<FileTree>`'s render method? @Milos Mosovsky